# Ionic router failed

Tags: ionic-framework

I have used `ion-tabs` and `side-menu` for change route the app, both uses `routerLink`. And when i press Home tab in `ion-tab` to go back to home page inside other pages, route changed to home but home page `constructor` method and `onInit` methods does not invoke.

`side-menu.component.ts`

```
<ion-app>
  <ion-split-pane contentId="main-content">
    
    <ion-menu *ngIf="isAuthenticated$ | async"  contentId="main-content" type="overlay">
      <ion-content>
        <ion-list id="inbox-list">

          <div class="menu-header">
            <ion-list-header>
               <img src="assets/wa-logo.ico">
            </ion-list-header>
            <ion-note></ion-note>
          </div>
          
         
          <ion-menu-toggle auto-hide="false" *ngFor="let p of appPages; let i = index">
            <ion-item (click)="selectedIndex = i" routerDirection="root" [routerLink]="[p.url]" lines="none" detail="false" [class.selected]="selectedIndex == i">
              <ion-icon slot="start" [ios]="p.icon + '-outline'" [md]="p.icon + '-sharp'"></ion-icon>
              <ion-label>{{ p.title }}</ion-label>
            </ion-item>
          </ion-menu-toggle>
        </ion-list>
      </ion-content>

      <ion-footer>
        <ion-menu-toggle auto-hide="false">
            <ion-item
              (click)="logout()"
              routerDirection="root"
              lines="none"
              detail="true"
            >
              <ion-icon
                slot="start"
                ios='log-out-outline'
                md="log-out-sharp"
              ></ion-icon>
              <ion-label> Logout </ion-label>
            </ion-item>
          </ion-menu-toggle>
        </ion-footer> 
    </ion-menu>
    <ion-router-outlet id="main-content"></ion-router-outlet>
    
    <ion-tabs *ngIf="isAuthenticated$ | async">

      <ion-tab-bar [translucent]="true" slot="fixed">
        <ion-tab-button (click)="onClick()">
          <ion-icon name="home"></ion-icon>
          <ion-label> Home </ion-label>
        </ion-tab-button>
    
        <ion-tab-button [routerLink]="['/features/new-request']">
          <ion-icon name="document-text"></ion-icon>
          <ion-label> New Request </ion-label>
        </ion-tab-button>
        
        <ion-tab-button [routerLink]="['/features/prev-requests']">
          <ion-icon name="reader"></ion-icon>
          <ion-label> All Requests </ion-label>
        </ion-tab-button>
      </ion-tab-bar>
    </ion-tabs>
  </ion-split-pane>
</ion-app>
```

So if i go inside prev-request page using `ion-tab` and once using hardware back button or `ion-toolbar` back button to changes route back to home page `constructor` and `ngOnInit` does not invoke, but if i route using side menu and go back with hardware back button or `ion-toolbar` back button `constructor` and `ngOnInit` methods are invoked.

`prev-req.page`

```
 constructor(private _preReqService: PrevReqService,private platform: Platform, 
            private _modal: ModalService,
            private _router: Router) { 
    this.platform.backButton.subscribeWithPriority(10, () => {
      this._router.navigate(['/features/home'])
    });
   }
```

Still i don't have any clue why this happens.

Any idea why this happens ?

Comment: Can you please post your code here

Comment: use ionic lifecycle hooks.

Comment: @NajamUsSaqib, can you provide some example ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to execute a function every time you go to a page Use `Ionic Page Life Cycle`.

`ionViewWillEnter:` Fired when the component routing to is about to animate into view.

`ionViewDidEnter:`  Fired when the component routing to has finished animating.

`ionViewWillLeave:` Fired when the component routing from is about to animate.

`ionViewDidLeave:`  Fired when the component routing to has finished animating.

```
export class ExamplePage implements OnInit {

  constructor(){
  }

 ionViewWillEnter(){
    console.log('Will Enter Fired') // will fire every time to go to a page. 
 }
}
```

[Ionic Life Cycle Docs](https://ionicframework.com/docs/angular/lifecycle)